# How do I speed up this code for building a list of all files in a network directory?

Tags: vb.net, .net, system.io.directory

I have a WPF program that grabs all of the directories within a certain network directory and lists them in a listview.

The problems is that there is so many directories that it can take up to 5 seconds for the list to load.

I am wondering if there is a way to speed this up with more efficient code. Or maybe even a way to store the list in an array and just look for changes every time after the first?

```
For Each i As String In Directory.GetDirectories(dir)
    If File.Exists(Path.GetFullPath(i) & "\cover.jpg") Then
        If (File.GetAttributes(Path.GetFullPath(i)) And FileAttributes.Hidden) <> FileAttributes.Hidden Then
            Dim foldername As String = Path.GetFileName(i)
            Dim moviename As String = foldername
            If moviename.Length > 4 Then
                If moviename.Substring(0, 4) = "The " Then
                    moviename = moviename.Remove(0, 4)
                End If
            End If
            Dim display As Boolean = True
            If IO.Directory.GetDirectories(Path.GetFullPath(i)).Length < 1 Then
                If IO.Directory.GetFiles(Path.GetFullPath(i), "*.avi").Length < 1 Then
                    If IO.Directory.GetFiles(Path.GetFullPath(i), "*.mp4").Length < 1 Then
                        If IO.Directory.GetFiles(Path.GetFullPath(i), "*.mkv").Length < 1 Then
                            display = False
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
            If display = True Then
                Showslist.Items.Add(New With {Key .img = Path.GetFullPath(i) & "\cover.jpg", .name = foldername, .path = Path.GetFullPath(i), .created = Directory.GetCreationTime(Path.GetFullPath(i)), .moviename = moviename})
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Comment: If you can, make sure the location is indexed by windows. This will make it about 10 times faster.

Comment: How would i go about trying this? and what are the disadvantages?

Comment: In Windows Explorer, right-click on the folder/drive and choose properties. The check the box that says something like "Allow files in this ?? to have ...Indexed". Depending on where you do this, you may have to click an "Advanced" button in the properties window. The disadvantages are minimal unless you are using an SSD. Then it is not recommended because of the excessive reads that will decrease the life of your drive.

Answer (score 2):

**1. Do not read the contents of a directory more than once.** Instead, read all required content once and cache it in a (in-memory) variable. This will help performance because accessing memory is a lot faster than doing I/O (here: accessing the file system). For example:

> ```
> If IO.Directory.GetFiles(…, "*.avi").Length < 1 Then
>     If IO.Directory.GetFiles(…, "*.mp4").Length < 1 Then
>         If IO.Directory.GetFiles(…, "*.mkv").Length < 1 Then
>             …
> ```

You just queried the same directory three times. You could change this to only read the contents once (thus potentially speeding up your code up to three times), and then filter it in-memory:

```
'Imports System.IO
'Imports System.Linq

' access the file system only once and store the results in-memory…
Dim filePaths As String() = Directory.GetFiles(…, "*")

' … and perform everything else on that in-memory cache:
If Not filePaths.Any(Function(fp) Path.GetExtension(fp) = ".avi") Then
    If Not filePaths.Any(…) Then
        If Not filePaths.Any(…) Then
            …
```

> <sub>**P.S.:** Perhaps it's worth pointing out that unlike `Directory.GetFiles`, the `System.IO.Path` methods should not cause expensive file system hits: They simply operate on strings that are known to contain file system paths.</sub>

---

**2. Consider reading the root directory's complete contents recursively.** The `Directory.GetFiles` method has an overload [`Directory.GetFiles(String, String, SearchOption)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms143316.aspx) whose [`SearchOption`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms143448.aspx) parameter can be set to `SearchOption.AllDirectories`. In that case, you will not only get the contents from the specified directory itself, but also from all of its sub-directories.

That means, you would need a single one call to `Directory.GetFiles` (for the root directory) instead of many calls, which means you're again reducing the number of expensive I/O calls. Store the results in an array and proceed to build your WPF list from there.

```
' read the contents of the network root directory, including all of its sub-directories…
Dim filePaths As String() = Directory.GetFiles(…, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)

' …and do everything else using the in-memory cache built above:
For Each filePath As String in filePaths
    …
    Showslist.Items.Add(…)
Next
```

Comment: I got all of that working, but it does not seem to be any faster.

Comment: What *part of* the code is actually slow? If it is the only remaining `Directory.GetFiles` call that takes so much time (5 minutes you said, right?), then perhaps I took you in the wrong direction. In that case, it might be better to shift the directory/file scanning to a background thread, scan directories one after another, and update the UI list after each directory. It's still going to take 5 minutes, but the UI should appear more responsive instead of just blocking completely for 5 minutes.

Comment: The problem is, the list is pretty much the whole UI.